# Tools for accumulating pixel values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, model, agent-based-modeling

Some months ago I was asking for ideas in order to do a displacement model of a lost person with GIS. This model would represent the displacement of a person by a terrain with some costs paramethers like slope, vegetation… So, I already have my model almost done. I have managed to do a final Raster where each pixel have a time value that represents the time in seconds that is needed to cross it.

Do you know if there is any tool in ArcGIS that accumulates these pixels from a starting point until a máximum of accumulated time? Let me explain:

In the model there would be a starting point, for example in .shp format. From this starting point, the tool could be able to accumulate the value of each pixel until it reaches 3600 seconds in order to simúlate the displacement of one person in one hour. The result should be a “circle” or isochrone, that represents the area until the accumulation of 3600 seconds.

Comment: You're basically describing the Cost Distance tool. Can you describe why it doesn't quite fit your needs? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cost-distance.htm

Comment: I can see no previous posts from you on this site.  Where did you ask this "some months ago"?